# RSpec の let と let! の違いは？

Tags: rspec

勉強していると、わかりそうでわからない事が出てきました。

[インスタンス変数を見直したがほうがいい理由](https://shinkufencer.hateblo.jp/entry/2019/02/01/233000)

上記の記事を読むと、このように書いてありました。

> let だと必要なタイミングで呼び出されるが、before でのインスタンス変数定義だと全ての場合に呼び出される。そのため context などで場合わけしたときに不要な場面でも作られることになる。
>
> RSpecの場合、レコード生成やDBアクセスが実行時間に影響するケースが多いのでなるべくであれば生成する契機は少なくしたほうがいいので、そのような観点でもインスタンス変数は避けたほうがいい。

では、逆に `let!` を使わないと行けない場合はどんな場合なのだろう、という事がわかりません。

遅延評価したら、困る事はあるのでしょうか？

初心者ですので、なんとか易しめに教えて頂けると嬉しいです。
よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1):

```
class Article < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :comments
end

class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :article
end
```

上記のようなモデルがあった時に、

```
let(:article) { create(:article) }
let(:article_comments) { create_list(:comment, 3, article_id: article.id) }

it 'has 3 comments' do
  num_comments = article.comments.count
  expect(num_comments).to eq article_comments.count
end
```

これはエラーになると思います。というのも、最初の `num_comments` を計算している段階では、 `article_comments` は呼び出されておらず、結果、 `num_comments` は `0` になるからです。

上記の例で言えば、 `article_comments` を `let!` 指定すると、意図通りに動くかと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます！！

num_comments = article.comments.count
の行に来たときに、
let(:article) { create(:article) }
は呼び出されるけれど
article_commentsというキーワード単体ではまだ登場していないから、
let(:article_comments) { create_list(:comment, 3, article_id: article.id) }
この部分は呼ばれておらず、コメントも作られてない、
結果、num_commentsが0になってしまう。ということですね！

すごいわかりやすいです、、
この場合、article_commentsを
commentsが登場する前に定義して、コメントを作っておかないといけないというイメージでしょうか、、